# How to open preference dialog box in android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

Scenario:

1. User make a call
2. update the associated field in preferences just after initiating the call
3. Next time user open the app and if the value of preference is set true
4. Open the preferred `dialog_box`

I am using `Android annotation` to set / update the preference. What I am not able to understand "How can I open preference dialog box just after user ended the call or when it returns back" ?

Should `extends Application` can help me in this?

Possible and worst solution could be:

1. Add `dialog box` to each activity of the app.
2. Check the preference value un `OnResume` and open the dialog_box.

I don't want to add redundant code to each activity. Is there any other better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library. That will allow you to get rid of redundant code.

> Android optimized event bus that simplifies communication between
>   Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. Less code, better
>   quality.

[Website](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

Comment: How EventBus can help in this scenario? Let's say i initiated the push notification but to receive this notification I need to check in each activity whether there is a notification exist or not? Am I correct?

Comment: just trigger the event at the start of each activity. In the event handler, check to see if you want to display the dialog or not using the preference value.

Comment: So, I can also do the same thing in `OnResume()`. check preference value and open the dialog Boxes (As I mentioned in Post).

Comment: the code to create and show the dialog will not need to be replicated in all activities. it goes in the event handler. It will be just one line in all activities to trigger the event. And i dont think you can go any lesser than that. You should have at least that much to take an action.